# Add, subtract, divide, multiply decimals

Tags: javascript

For JavaScript:

```
var add = function(calculate){
 var number1 =  document.getElementById('number1').value; 
  var number2 =  document.getElementById('number2').value; 
 document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML= parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
};

var subtraction = function(calculate){
  var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML= parseInt(number1)  -  parseInt(number2);
};

var multiply = function(calculate){
  var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML= parseInt(number1) * parseInt(number2);
};

var divide = function(calculate){
  var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML= parseInt(number1) / parseInt(number2);
};
```

For HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cool.css"/>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="box" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; border: 2px solid #000;">
        <div id="enter1">
        <p>Number 1: <input id='number1' value="ENTER 1"type="number"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="enter2">
        <p>Number 2: <input id='number2' type="number" value="ENTER 2"></p>
      </div>
      <button id="add"onclick='add()' style="font-size: 25px; background-color: #00B85C">ADD</button>
      <button id="sub" onclick='subtraction()' style="font-size: 25px; background-color: #FF6600;">SUBTRACT</button>
      <button id="multi"onclick='multiply()' style="font-size: 25px; background-color: #2E8AE6">MULTIPLY</buuton>
      <button id="div"onclick='divide()'  style="font-size: 25px; background-color: #CC6699;">DIVIDE</button>
      </div>
         <div id="box2" style="width: 800px; heigth: 600px; border 2px solid #000;">
         <p id='calculate'>ANSWER HERE</p>
       </div>
    </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

'number1' and 'number2' are the names for the input tags in HTML. I forget the reason I inserted 'calculate' as a parameter; if you think it is unnecessary, could you explain why(it helps me understand the code more `;)` )

'calculate', though, is the ID I gave to the paragraph tag where the answer will show.

I want to add(didn't want to write out the rest) with decimals. Right now, it just adds whole numbers. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat`

Comment: What do you need the `calculate` parameter for?

Comment: @adeneo(concerning your answer) What does `parseFloat` do??

Comment: It parses to a float rather than an integer, see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` will only return integer values. You need to use `parseFloat`.

Also, when using `parseInt`, it's a good idea to pass a radix value (e.g. `parseInt(text, 10);`). `parseFloat` doesn't need it.

Comment: What does does `parseFloat` do? Concerning `parseInt`: Why must I insert a `text` parameter and the `10` in there?? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It turns a string representation of a decimal value into a `Number` object with an underlying type with more precision than an integer (i.e. `parseInt` will only return integer values; `parseFloat` can return decimal values). `text` is not an actual parameter, it was a placeholder. You would use a string or another variable instead. The radix of `10` says "let's work in base-10". It's good practice to specify it as to not incorrectly parse numbers in different formats such as octal.

Comment: Oooooohhh... ok! Thank you for your help! I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function over(a,b){
        let z = a+b;
        let div = z/2
        return div;
    }
    let r=  over(2,2);
    document.write(r);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).